# Using setView with builder?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I am trying to get my hands on Dialogs in Android. I recently came across this example which makes use of the Builder class.

The code is

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_show_note, null);
```

Next it shows to this line of code

```
builder.setView(dialogView).setMessage("Add a new note");
```

Now just as I enter this line, the error message that pops up is "Can not resolve setView"

I am not sure what mistake I am making or there is some error in the book. 
Does Builder class even contains *setView method*?

The full code example upto the error is as follows:-

```
public class DialogNewNote extends DialogFragment { 
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater(); 
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_note, null); 

        builder.setView(dialogView).setMessage("Add a new note"); //error

    } 
}
```

Comment: "Next it shows..." What source are you citing?

Comment: To find what methods a class has, you can look at the API docs.

Comment: It's actually from a book!

Comment: Please show a complete code example. Include the class and methods, not just single lines of code.

Comment: And even if the class does not have I would still need a correct solution for my query.

Comment: We cannot answer your query without more context.

Comment: These were the main lines that I thought would suffice. I think the rest are redundant. But alright.

Comment: Much of the rest is probably irrelevant, but it is difficult to tell. You should at a minimum provide a class and a methods which contains the lines of code you are asking about.

Comment: [AlertDialog.Builder has a setView() method.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView(android.view.View)) So the code you have given cannot cause the claimed compile error if the three lines are in the same method. If you want an answer, you must provide more cute.

Comment: Done, Please have a look.

Comment: Note that none of the findViewById() lines pertain to this question, so I removed them. On the other hand, the class and method are important context.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this should compile. I am assuming you have the correct import statement for AlertDialog.

Comment: of course 'import android.app.AlertDialog;'

It is still showing in red. What could be wrong?

Comment: Did you try it out? Please tell.

Comment: I have not tried it myself. As far as I can tell, it should work. I do not see anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and i think you should place your code inside onCreate rather than onCreateDilaog.On the other hand if its the same dialog for which you have extended to dialog class then you should provide the layout inflator in the onCreateView method as in normal fragment.

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        View dialogView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
        builder.setView(dialogView).setMessage("kqhwdi");
    }
```

for achieving a separate alert dialog i think you should create it in onCreate() or in onViewCreated().

Comment: So you are implying the above code in the book is wrong?

Comment: No. I just tried doing it your way and got the error.but in oncreate it worked fine.i am saying you try it this way and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: There was no my way, I just cited the book's example. Though as you said it works. But I wanted to make out what error is there on the book?